# How I can access a private static member variable via the class constructor?

Tags: c++, static, private

How can I use and modify the `s_member` private static variable from the constructor or in general from an other member function?

This is what I tried.

a.h:

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#include <set>

class A
{
    public:
        A();
        virtual ~A();

    private:
        static std::set<int> s_member;
};

#endif
```

a.cpp:

```
#include "a.h"

A::A()
{
    A::s_member.insert(5); // It causes error.
}
```

I get this error:

```
/tmp/ccBmNUGs.o: In function `A::A()': a.cpp:(.text+0x15): undefined
 reference to `A::s_member' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: To use it, you must first define it. You just declared it. See the links in the other comments for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared `A::s_member` but not defined it yet. To define it, put below code, outside of class:

```
std::set<int> A::s_member;
```

For example:

```
std::set<int> A::s_member;

A::A()
{
  // ...
}
```

The problem is not related to accessing and `private`/`public`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the variable

```
#include "a.h"

std::set<int> A::s_member;

A::A()
{
    A::s_member.insert(5); // It causes error.
}
```

The reference to object file `ccBmNUGs.o` in the error message says that it is an error of the linker.
The linker can not find the definition of `s_member`